# White mold on my corney kegs?

Tags: cleaning, corny-keg, mold

I've got a basic beer serving fridge out in the garage, just a few taps on the front and some bottles on the door. I'm developing a problem with what looks kinda like mold, I notice it mostly on the black rubberish top area but some on the stainless as well. It looks like it was peppered with a bunch of little tiny snowballs, white round and spread pretty evenly with some areas more concentrated then others. The mold substance isn't on anything else in the fridge; not on the walls or the bottles or on the door beer/gas lines... I have heard of people developing a mold on the ceiling of their sour cellars and it sounds like a "good" thing?

What's going on? What is it? How do I get rid of it?

Fridge temp: mid 30's

It has been going on for about 2-3 months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably from having too high of a humidity level in the fridge. I have this same problem in my fermentation fridge (develops darker spots of mold) and my keezer (no mold but moisture pools at the bottom of the freezer).

I just make it a point to wipe out the excess moisture from the walls of these two whenever I am messing with beer. I have considered using something like DampRid(?), which is that stuff that absorbs moisture from the air, but I don't know if it will be cost effective to do so.

Bottom line: so long as the moisture isn't causing corrosion on any non-stainless metal, and so long as the mold isn't getting **into** the actual beer, I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Ya it is an old fridge freezer combo and moisture hasn't really been an issue over the past couple years but its there for sure! It doesn't seem to be corrosive and in fact seems to be very delicate, wipes off easy but come back quick. Been doing everything I can to keep things sanitary when hooking any lines up or anywhere else it could get in. Thanks so far Graham!

Answer (score 1):

I get the odd spot of mould developing in my keg fridge from time to time, particularly when switching between serving and fermentation temperatures. I keep a bottle of diluted bleach or sanitising solution in a spray bottle and give the inside of the fridge a good spray when raising the temperature of if I spot some mould developing.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a leaky seal on the fridge that's letting moist warm air in, where it condenses. Or if your fridge has a condensation runoff tube, it might be blocked.